# How to do multiple nested route with Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a folder component with routing.  Every time I click on it, the same component is loaded with a new api call and the foldername as the  query parameter. I can't add children forever, right? What can I do?

/folders/f1/f1-1/f1-1-1

```
window.router = new VueRouter({
routes: [
...
{
    path: '/folder',
    component: require('./components/folder.vue'),
    children: [
        {
            path: '/folder:folderName',
            name: 'innerFolder'
            component: require('./components/folder.vue')
        },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a variable number of elements that are not predetermined in advance, append an asterisk (*) to the end of the variable name. In that case, the value of the variable will be an array containing each invoked element, delimited by the slash (/) character.

```js
window.router = new VueRouter({
routes: [
...
{
    path: '/folder',
    component: require('./components/folder.vue'),
    children: [
        {
            path: '/folder/:folderName*', // add * ends of variable name
            name: 'innerFolder'
            component: require('./components/folder.vue')
        },
}
```

If path example: **`http://example.com/folder/f1/f1-1/f1-1-1`**,
value of folderName:

```json
[
  "f1",
  "f1-1",
  "f1-1-1"
]
```

Another example: **`http://example.com/folder/testfolder/sub-testfolder/sub-subtestfolder/images/profile.jpg`**,
value of folderName:

```json
[
  "testfolder",
  "sub-testfolder",
  "sub-subtestfolder",
  "images",
  "profile.jpg"
]
```

This way, you can easily determine if a file was invoked instead of a folder because the last element of the array will contain at least one dot (.)

[Repeatable route with Vue-Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#repeatable-params)